# Kafka Compaction for topic

Tags: apache-kafka

I have used `kafka-topics.bat --zookeeper localhost:2181 --alter --topic test --config cleanup.policy=compact delete config min.cleanable.dirty.ratio=0.01 --config segment.ms=100 --config delete.retention.ms=100` to compact my topic.
I have sent 2000 messages with same key.When I consume those messages i get each message separately rather than one compacted message.

Comment: how did you solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The compaction setting you're referring to is not related to how you consume messages with a Kafka client. Please check the [official documentation here](https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#compaction) for further details.

If you want to control how your client consume messages you have to configure your client using the [client config properties](https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#consumerconfigs).

Consider a situation where you're pooling the topic for 300 milliseconds and receives a group of messages(ConsumerRecords) that you can then iterate over to process each message independently.

```
while(true) {
   ConsumerRecords<String, JsonNode> records = kafkaConsumer.poll(300);
       if(records.count() > 0) {
          for(ConsumerRecord<String, JsonNode> record: records) {
             if(counter % 500 == 0) {
                 log.info("Record recovered, groupId: {}, topicName: {}, key: {}, value: {} , offset: {}",
                 this.groupId, this.topicNames, record.key(), record.value(), record.offset());
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: suppose we have something like this key=value1 key=value2 now value2 is the updated value for key and i want only the updated value !!! how do I configure Kafka to retain only the updated value ?

Comment: Hi, you can't retain only the latest info, that's not how kafka work, it's an append only distributed log, for what you mentioned you'll need to use kafka streams and Ktable or GlobalKTable that were introduced in kafka 0.10.1 or 0.10.0 as far as I remember not sure by now.... https://www.confluent.io/blog/introducing-kafka-streams-stream-processing-made-simple/

https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/streams#streams_kstream_ktable